# Magento 2 How Sales Graph Work on Dashboard

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-enterprise-2

Can anyone Explain How Sales graph on Magento Dashboard work.?

can anyone explain what the numbers are showing on this report?

[image: Sales Graph Orders]

[image: Sales Graph Amount]

Comment: I think you ned to refer magento documentation buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Orders tab displays a chart of all orders during the specified time period. 
For example: On 6/19/18 there where 30 orders placed and 90 on 6/20/18

Below the chart is the total revenue, tax, shipping, and quantity ordered.

The Amounts tab displays a chart of all order amounts during the specified time period.
For example: On 6/19/18 there where orders placed worth $22 and $64 on 6/20/18

I am assuming you are getting confused because of the numbers on the Y-axis. The numbers may not be correct or not as you expected. This may be because of the issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7927

For more details on the dashboard chart, you can go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/stores/admin-dashboard.html

Comment: 3 Orders are Placed on 19/06/2018  of Total amount $478.22   and 
9 Orders are Placed on 20/06/2018  of Total amount $1214.22

Comment: Yes now i get Proper Chart.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7927 solve problem

you are correct Issue  was with Y-axes